# remove unwanted characters from the beginning of titles

Tags: php, mysql

table `arts` column `title` - example:

```
1122 A TITLE
025 - ANOTHER TITLE
1/7 - SOME TITLE
1 4 5 - SOME ANOTHER TITLE
```

I need to remove everything before the real title.

Characters for removing are - everything except letters (titles should start with a letter).

So I need something like:

```
update arts set title = replace(title, 'everything except letters on the beginning', '');
```

Using `php` or `mysql` inside `phpmyadmin`.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to match anything up to first letter, then capture the rest.

```
$arr = ["1122 A TITLE",
"025 - ANOTHER TITLE",
"1/7 - SOME TITLE",
"1 4 5 - SOME ANOTHER TITLE"];

foreach($arr as $val){
    preg_match("/.*?([a-zA-Z].*)/", $val, $m);
    echo $m[1] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
A TITLE
ANOTHER TITLE
SOME TITLE
SOME ANOTHER TITLE
```

https://3v4l.org/4sZ9I

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it out with a regular expression:

```
$matches = []
if (preg_match("/^([0-9\-\_/ ]{0,})(.{0,})/", $string, $matches)) {
    $filtered = $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to do all these operations at PHP side, because mysql does not support this, If you really want to do this at MySQL side then you need to write your own custom function,

Try with PHP code as follow.

```
$string = '1 4 5 - SOME ANOTHER TITLE';
$pattern = '/^[^a-zA-Z]{1,}/';
$replacement = '';
$title = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

$qry = 'update arts set title = "'.$title.'"';

echo $qry;
```

Above code will generate output as follow

**update arts set title = "SOME ANOTHER TITLE"**

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80e533ec27aa7eb104c473b2ea3c4953a379dd57)